# Disabling toggling

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have been working with reporting services in visual studio 2008 lately and I am confronted with a problem. Is there anyway to dismiss the toggling feature for a group, if a value does not fulfill the requirements?

Comment: do you mean making certain members of the group "expandlable/collapsable" based on an expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to set up a separate column for your toggle item (rather than using an existing column) since you will need to set the visibility of the toggle item to Hidden where drilldown is to be disabled.

You can find further details of this approach [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/179b832e-86b6-4e5b-8deb-a38fbf81ecce/).